# How to improve the way I browse an array with .each while trying to keep track of the index ("i") using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I'm doing a simple `.each` but I still want to keep the position in the loop, I can do:

```
i = 0
poneys.each do |poney|
  #something involving i
  #something involving poney
  i = i + 1
end
```

This doesn't look very elegant to me. So I guess I could get rid of the `.each`:

```
for i in 0..poneys.size-1 do
  #something involving i
end
```

... or something similar with a different syntax.

The problem is that if I want to access the object I have to do:

```
for i in 0..poneys.size-1 do
  poney = poneys[i]
  #something involving i
  #something involving poney
end
```

... and that's not very elegant either.

Is there a nice and clean way of doing this ?

Comment: I wasn't able to come up with a simple and meaningful title. Anyone with a better idea, please go ahead and fix it

Comment: For future reference, 0..poneys.size-1 is not very elegant, I think you can use 0...poneys.size instead.

Comment: @aistina: it would break since I'd try to access poneys[poneys.size] and arrays are indexed from 0

Comment: No, note the triple dot (...) instead of the double dot (..). IIRC, that does the -1 for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003137)

From the official documentation:

> Calls block with two arguments, the
>   item and its index, for each item in
>   enum.
>
> ```
> hash = Hash.new
> %w(cat dog wombat).each_with_index do |item, index|
>     hash[item] = index
> end
> hash   #=> {"cat"=>0, "wombat"=>2, "dog"=>1}
> ```

Comment: ok it works perfectly, thank you, you made my day. I was sure there was a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Depends what do you do with poneys :) `Enumerable#inject` is also a nice one for such things:

```
poneys.inject(0) do |i, poney|
  i += 1; i
end
```

I learned a lot about `inject` from http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/03/ruby-inject.html which is great article.